# Available camera area in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

The available camera area is standard in the game looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNVPO.png)

When you change the screen horizontally, the game objects get smaller.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLgCd.png)

If you change the screen vertically, the game area is cropped.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l9S2.png)

I want the same thing to happen when changing vertically as when changing horizontally. The game objects should shrink, and empty space should appear at the top and bottom.

Tell me how to do it, please.

Comment: the actual game objects arent smaller in the second, look at the height the same amount is visible, the only difference is the width.  Same is true when you then turn it horizontal, the same amount is visible top to bottom.